# Equivalent in Octave / Matlab for R head() and tail() functions

Tags: r, matlab, octave

What are the equivalent ways to calling the beginning (or ending) of a data set in Octave / MATLAB?

These are incredibly useful functions to avoid printing out the entire dataset on the console, and get an idea of the headings and type of data.

It would be great to also have an equivalent for `str()` along the same lines...

Comment: What type of data are you trying to visualize?

Comment: A regular data.frame with variables as columns and subjects/observations as rows.

Comment: So just a matrix since MATLAB doesn't have dataframes....?

Comment: since you seem to come from an R background, the [dataframe package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/dataframe/index.html) may be helpful (it doesn't answer your question but considering your last questions, it may come in handy soon).

Comment: How do you install new packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in but you can easily grab the first `N` rows or the last `M` rows.

```
A = rand(10000, 2);

% First 10 rows
A(1:10, :)

% Last 10 columns
A((end-9):end,:)
```

The same will work if you are using a `table` to store your data.

```
t = table(rand(10000,1), rand(10000,1));
t(1:10,:)
t((end-9):end,:)
```

Or a `dataset`

```
d = dataset(rand(10000,1), rand(10000,1))
d(1:10,:)
d((end-9):end,:)
```

You could easily create the following `head()` and `tail()` anonymous functions which you could use to do this easily.

```
tail = @(data)disp(data(max(size(data, 1)-9, 1):end,:));
head = @(data)disp(data(1:min(10, size(data,1)),:));
```

And use them like a normal function

```
head(d)
```

Comment: After using python for a while and switching back I completely forgot the basics of Octave. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Variables editor](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/view-edit-and-copy-variables.html) can be useful for quickly inspecting your data. There's also a handy keyboard shortcut to open your variable in the editor - select the variable name (either in editor or in command window) and press `ctrl+D`. It also displays structure arrays quite nicely - often that's much easier than inspecting through command window.